# Can Ionic receive push notifications without Push Service?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering if ionic apps can receive push notifications wihout Push Service. I mean if one ionic app can register in Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to receive push notifications without intermediation of that Push service offered by Ionic Cloud. A direct ionic app -> FCM integration is what I'm trying to figure out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question to FCM speficially, then yes it is possible to send push notifications to both iOS and Android using FCM and [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase).

Checkout this [Git Repo](https://github.com/edismooth/ionic2-firebase/tree/master) for a great demo using it! Go over the README for setup and you can begin tinkering around with it.

EDIT: Forgot to mention this project is for Ionic 2, not Ionic 1.

Answer (score 0):

To receive push notification messages, you could use the plugin [Phonegap Plugin Push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

I tested it on iOS and Android and works very well.